# An exception occurred in AD claim provider when calling SPClaimProvider.FillResolveClaim

Tags: authentication, ad

2013 on prem farm with Active Directory claims authentication and 2012 R2 Servers.

Certain people are unable to open items in lists that they have submitted items to.  Other's, including myself, cannot edit these items either. You can view the properties but when trying to edit, the system just spins until if finally times out, getting the dreaded "Sorry, something went wrong" message.  Upon looking in the logs, they all have this error message in common:

"An exception occurred in AD claim provider when calling SPClaimProvider.FillResolveClaim(): Thread was being aborted.."

Another issue we are seeing, that I'm certain is related, is with people picker fields that are taking a long time to authenticate the users accounts.  If there are too many accounts added in one people picker it will error out eventually. We have found that if we use the users login name (as opposed to their last name, first name) it appears to authenticate users much faster.

This started happening on March 26th right after we did the latest Microsoft farm updates and server updates.

Comment: Are any of your DCs unreachable by the SharePoint servers (i.e. due to firewall, subnetting configs, etc.)? Do you have DCs in the same data center as the SharePoint servers?

Comment: Trevor - all domain controllers are reachable by the SP servers. Thanks for the question!